# Find the Apex of a Cone, the Sphere inscribed in it is known

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Sorry for my bad english.

I'm working in 3D/Space.
I have a Sphere inscribed in a Cone :

- The center of the Sphere is known. I'm calling it C(x0, y0, z0).
- The radius of the Sphere is known. I'm calling it R.
- The apex (the top vertex) of the Cone is unknown. I'm calling it A(x, y, z).
- Finally, I also have a direction vector V(x1, y1, z1) that describe the line AC. NB : The length of V is not equal to R.
- The segment EF have the length equal to 2 * R and is the diameter of the sphere.

So here is a representation of the problem :
[image]

The goal is to find the point A (x, y, z) that solve the problem.
I am looking for a solution for about 3hours (thales,...) and I do not have much time to lose.

Can you help me ?

Thank you :)

Comment: There is no unique solution.  Proof: Consider point A', which is placed to the left of A in your diagram.  If you make A' the new apex of the cone, what has to change?  The center of the sphere? No.  The radius of the sphere? No.  The direction of vector V? No.

Comment: I think, I should have mentioned that the circle described by the sphere and the cone (the circle that touch both the sphere and the cone) have a diameter equal to 2 * R.
I added this constraint if the image but not in my question ^^ I'm editing my first post to add this constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no solution. For the lines AE and AF to be tangent to the sphere, they would have to be parallel (since both are at right angles to EF). That's a contradiction, since they intersect at A.

Comment: Why are you saying that the lines AE and AF should be tangent to the sphere ? Is it because the sphere is inscribed in the cone ?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you don't want any part of the sphere to be outside the cone, and you want the sphere to touch the cone, I think they have to be tangent lines.

Comment: Ok thank you :) It saves me other hours of research ^^ +1 for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Either...

1) The surface of the sphere either does not intersect at all with the surface of the cone,

2) The surface of the sphere shares TWO circular intersection lines with the surface of the cone,

3) If the surface of the sphere shares a single circular intersection with the cone, then the perimeter of the circular plane of EF cannot run along the surface of the cone if equal to the diameter of the sphere with the given constraints,

4) Or these objects are not of the laws our universe except I *think* *maybe* if these object were *hypothetically* moving at the speed of light? I call trick question or bogus quiz....

Comment: Heh! +1 for special relativity.